# Javascript slideshow buttons overlapping fancybox upon scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I have a javascript library setup on http://www.topholidayrecipes.com/crockpot-chicken-recipes.html  and this page uses fancy box (located in the recipe box named "iframe" ). The problem is that everytime the scroll function is used inside and outside the fancybox...the play and pause buttons from the javascript slideshow are overlapping the fancybox and its content. How would I go on to solve this problem. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `z-index`es:

- .dg-image-gallery-next-autoplay-containe is 20000
- .fancybox-opened is 1003

Make fancybox's z-index bigger than the play buttons.

PS. you could use `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:scroll` to get rid of the horizontal scrollbars in some of your elements.